# I want to know difference between "delete-orphan" and "all-delete-orphan" cascade styles in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0

From my understanding,
Cascade= "all"   is equal to cascade="save-update,delete"

and

Cascade= "all-delete-orphan"  is equal to cascade= "save-update,delete-orphan"
is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-transitive) says:

> For each basic operation of the Hibernate session - including persist(), merge(), saveOrUpdate(), delete(), lock(), refresh(), evict(), replicate() - there is a corresponding cascade style. Respectively, the cascade styles are named create, merge, save-update, delete, lock, refresh, evict, replicate. If you want an operation to be cascaded along an association, you must indicate that in the mapping document. For example:
>
> ```
>    <one-to-one name="person" cascade="persist"/>
> ```
>
> Cascade styles my be combined:
>
> ```
>    <one-to-one name="person" cascade="persist,delete,lock"/>
> ```
>
> You can even use cascade="all" to specify that *all* operations should be cascaded along the association. The default cascade="none" specifies that no operations are to be cascaded.

Comment: my question was to compare the difference between
"delete-orphan" and "all-delete-orphan"

Comment: And, if you click the link to the documentation I gave you and scroll down a little, you'll have a complete explanation of what delete-orphan is, and when and how to use it. Why don't you read the documentation? That's what it has been written for: teach you how things work.